# Django get value from JSON data

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to play with an open fda API. So far everything works well. Issue is coming for nested JSON data.

Here is my Json data:

```
{
      "seriousnessother": "1",
      "reportduplicate": {
        "duplicatenumb": "US-BRISTOL-MYERS SQUIBB COMPANY-BMS-2017-086135",
        "duplicatesource": "BRISTOL MYERS SQUIBB"
      },
      "safetyreportversion": "1",
      "receiptdate": "20170927",
      "duplicate": "1",
      "seriousnessdeath": "1",
      "receivedate": "20170927",
      "patient": {
        "reaction": [
          {
            "reactionmeddrapt": "Death",
            "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1",
            "reactionoutcome": "5"
          },
          {
            "reactionmeddrapt": "Product use in unapproved indication",
            "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1",
            "reactionoutcome": "6"
          }
        ],
        "patientsex": "1",
        "drug": [
          {
            "drugstartdateformat": "102",
            "medicinalproduct": "OPDIVO",
            "drugindication": "COLORECTAL CANCER",
            "drugcharacterization": "1",
            "drugadministrationroute": "065",
            "drugenddateformat": "102",
            "drugseparatedosagenumb": "1",
            "drugstructuredosageunit": "032",
            "openfda": {
              "manufacturer_name": [
                "E.R. Squibb & Sons, L.L.C."
              ],
              "unii": [
                "31YO63LBSN"
              ],
              "product_type": [
                "HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG"
              ],
              "spl_set_id": [
                "f570b9c4-6846-4de2-abfa-4d0a4ae4e394"
              ],
              "route": [
                "INTRAVENOUS"
              ],
              "generic_name": [
                "NIVOLUMAB"
              ],
              "brand_name": [
                "OPDIVO"
              ],
              "product_ndc": [
                "0003-3772",
                "0003-3734",
                "0003-3774"
              ],
              "pharm_class_epc": [
                "Programmed Death Receptor-1 Blocking Antibody [EPC]"
              ],
              "substance_name": [
                "NIVOLUMAB"
              ],
              "spl_id": [
                "2d33126d-5115-459e-bcaf-d0ace4fbe94e"
              ],
              "pharm_class_moa": [
                "Programmed Death Receptor-1-directed Antibody Interactions [MoA]"
              ],
              "application_number": [
                "BLA125554"
              ],
              "nui": [
                "N0000191259",
                "N0000191260"
              ],
              "package_ndc": [
                "0003-3734-13",
                "0003-3772-11",
                "0003-3774-12"
              ]
            },
            "drugstructuredosagenumb": "1",
            "drugintervaldosageunitnumb": "2",
            "drugstartdate": "20160907",
            "actiondrug": "5",
            "activesubstance": {
              "activesubstancename": "NIVOLUMAB"
            },
            "drugintervaldosagedefinition": "803",
            "drugauthorizationnumb": "125554",
            "drugrecurreadministration": "3",
            "drugdosagetext": "1 DF, Q2WK",
            "drugenddate": "20161222",
            "drugadditional": "3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "occurcountry": "US",
      "reporttype": "1",
      "companynumb": "US-BRISTOL-MYERS SQUIBB COMPANY-BMS-2017-086135",
      "safetyreportid": "14015990",
      "sender": {
        "senderorganization": "FDA-Public Use",
        "sendertype": "2"
      },
      "transmissiondate": "20171128",
      "fulfillexpeditecriteria": "1",
      "transmissiondateformat": "102",
      "receiptdateformat": "102",
      "receiver": {
        "receiverorganization": "FDA",
        "receivertype": "6"
      },
      "serious": "1",
      "receivedateformat": "102",
      "primarysource": {
        "reportercountry": "US",
        "qualification": "5"
      },
      "primarysourcecountry": "US"
    }
```

Here is my view to call this data and convert to Django data.

```
json_data = open('/users/downloads/drug-bad.json').read()
    response = json.loads(json_data)
    a=0
    b=0
    for data in response['results']:
        #try:
            seriousnessother = data.get('seriousnessother')
            reportduplicate_duplicatenumb = data['reportduplicate'].get('duplicatenumb')
            reportduplicate_duplicatesource = data['reportduplicate'].get('duplicatesource')
            safetyreportversion = data.get('safetyreportversion')
            receiptdate = data.get('receiptdate')
            duplicate = data.get('duplicate')
            seriousnessdeath = data.get('seriousnessdeath')
            receivedate = data.get('receivedate')
            patient_reaction_reactionmeddrapt = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionmeddrapt')
            patient_reaction_reactionmeddraversionpt = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionmeddraversionpt')
            patient_reaction_reactionoutcome = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionoutcome')
            patient_patientsex = data['patient'].get('patientsex')
            patient_drug_medicinalproduct = data['patient']['drug'].get('medicinalproduct')
            patient_drug_drugindication = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugindication')
            patient_drug_drugcharacterization = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugcharacterization')
            patient_drug_drugadministrationroute = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugadministrationroute')
            patient_drug_drugseparatedosagenumb = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugseparatedosagenumb')
            patient_drug_drugstructuredosageunit = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugstructuredosageunit')
            patient_drug_openfda_manufacturer_name = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['manufacturer'].get('name')
            patient_drug_openfda_unii = data['patient']['drug']['openfda'].get('unii')
            patient_drug_openfda_product_type = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['product'].get('type')
            patient_drug_openfda_spl_set_id = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['spl']['set'].get('id')
            patient_drug_openfda_route = data['patient']['drug']['openfda'].get('route')
            patient_drug_openfda_generic_name = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['generic'].get('name')
            patient_drug_openfda_brand_name = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['brand'].get('name')
            patient_drug_openfda_product_ndc = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['product'].get('ndc')
            patient_drug_openfda_pharm_class_epc = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['pharm']['class'].get('epc')
            patient_drug_openfda_substance_name = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['substance'].get('name')
            patient_drug_openfda_spl_id = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['spl'].get('id')
            patient_drug_openfda_pharm_class_moa = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['pharm']['class'].get('moa')
            patient_drug_openfda_application_number = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['application'].get('number')
            patient_drug_openfda_nui = data['patient']['drug']['openfda'].get('nui')
            patient_drug_openfda_package_ndc = data['patient']['drug']['openfda']['package'].get('ndc')
            patient_drug_drugstructuredosagenumb = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugstructuredosagenumb')
            patient_drug_drugintervaldosageunitnumb = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugintervaldosageunitnumb')
            patient_drug_drugstartdate = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugstartdate')
            patient_drug_actiondrug = data['patient']['drug'].get('actiondrug')
            patient_drug_activesubstance_activesubstancename = data['patient']['drug']['activesubstance'].get('activesubstancename')
            patient_drug_drugintervaldosagedefinition = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugintervaldosagedefinition')
            patient_drug_drugauthorizationnumb = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugauthorizationnumb')
            patient_drug_drugrecurreadministration = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugrecurreadministration')
            patient_drug_drugdosagetext = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugdosagetext')
            patient_drug_drugenddate = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugenddate')
            patient_drug_drugadditional = data['patient']['drug'].get('drugadditional')
            occurcountry = data.get('occurcountry')
            reporttype = data.get('reporttype')
            companynumb = data.get('companynumb')
            safetyreportid = data.get('safetyreportid')
            sender_senderorganization = data['sender'].get('senderorganization')
            sender_sendertype = data['sender'].get('sendertype')
            fulfillexpeditecriteria = data.get('fulfillexpeditecriteria')
            receiver_receiverorganization = data['receiver'].get('receiverorganization')
            receiver_receivertype = data['receiver'].get('receivertype')
            serious = data.get('serious')
            primarysource_reportercountry = data['primarysource'].get('reportercountry')
            primarysource_qualification = data['primarysource'].get('qualification')
            primarysourcecountry = data.get('primarysourcecountry')
```

I am getting following error:

```
 patient_reaction_reactionmeddrapt = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionmeddrapt')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Note that there are many data in response result. It could be that one of result does not have patient field. But as get method should return None if it does not exist.
I want either the field value or None.
It works for simple Json data but error comes when there are array/list inside array/list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since reaction is list you should do something like this:

```
reactions = data['patient']['reaction']
if reactions and isinstance(reactions, list):
    for reaction in reactions:
        patient_reaction_reactionmeddrapt = reaction.get('reactionmeddrapt')
else:
    patient_reaction_reactionmeddrapt = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionmeddrapt')
```

instead of simple:

```
patient_reaction_reactionmeddrapt = data['patient']['reaction'].get('reactionmeddrapt')
```

`data['patient']['reaction']` in your code return list objects. So you need to iterate over it to get `reactionmeddrapt` for each list element.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input json:

```
"patient": {
    "reaction": [
      {
        "reactionmeddrapt": "Death",
        "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1",
        "reactionoutcome": "5"
      },
      {
        "reactionmeddrapt": "Product use in unapproved indication",
        "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1",
        "reactionoutcome": "6"
      }
    ],
```

The data value for "reactions" is a list. Also as I understand it, you want to get the "reactionmeddrapt" attribute value or None if you don't have a data value for "patient".

You could do something like this:

```
try:
    reactions = data['patient']['reaction']
except KeyError:
    return None
if reactions and isinstance(reactions, list):
    # Assuming you want to iterate over the list
    for reaction in reactions:
        reactionmeddrapt = reaction.get('reactionmeddrapt')
```